# Azure Data Factory - Null parameter in Stored Procedure activity

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a Stored Procedure activity in my Azure Data Factory pipeline that recalls the following stored procedure on Azure Synapse:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.procedure_name @portafoglio INT [...]
```

The activity in configured in order to use a variable (portafoglioElab), previously set in the pipeline:

[image]

My problem is how to pass a Null value as input parameter to the procedure via the Azure Data Factory Pipeline in the Store Procedure activity.
I've tried by setting the variable portafoglioElab with null, "null", None, @coalesce(null) but I'm not finding the right value corresponding to sql NULL.

This is the step of the pipeline where I set the variable:
[image]

It is a step inside the IF condition of the whole pipeline:
[image]

Indeed I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create Sql Source. Please double check the connection string, stored procedure are set with correct format. Error: The value of the property 'Value' is invalid for the stored procedure parameter 'portafoglio'.

Can please someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: _"The stored procedure allows the sql Null value"_ What do you mean by this? Stored Procedure parameters _can't_ be defined as `NOT NULL` unless you are using natively compiled procedures. As such (normally) _all_ Stored Procedure parameters can allow, as they _can't be configured_ to not to. Do you *actually* mean that the procedure's parameter's **default value** is `NULL`? This isn't the same as *allowing* the value `NULL`. Or are you actually using a natively compiled procedure?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your pipeline where you're attempting to add `NULL` as a parameter value?

Comment: @Larnu, my fault, I've added some information to my question. The problem is that I'm receiving errors when I try to pass the null value to the stored procedure as input parameter via a variable in the Azure Data Factory pipeline

Comment: If the parameter has a *default* value of `NULL`, why not just omit it, if you want it to be `NULL`?

Comment: @Larnu because it is an input parameter of the stored procedure, it can be Null or set during the execution of the Pipeline. If you don't pass it you get this error: Sql error number: 201. Error Message: Procedure or function 'NAME_OF_PROCEDURE' expects parameter '@portafoglio', which was not supplied.

Comment: @J.D. thanks, I've added some screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solutions with the dynamic content.

It is not only possible to put dynamic content in the value of the parameter, but even the parameter itself cam be dynamic.

[image]

I solved after many tests with this value:

```
@json(concat('{"portafoglio": {"value": ', variables('portafoglioElab'), '}}'))
```

In this way I can handle null and not null values.
Pay attention that the documentation is wrong, the content has to be a dictionary, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Pass -1 or some other sentinel and handle it in the proc

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, but if I have several procs I have to edit all of them, I prefer the previous given answer.